# SQL Server 2008 R2 install fails with a type load error

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got a VMWare virtual machine running Windows Server 2008 R2. I've installed the latest updates and the Windows SDK, and I'm in the process of installing SQL Server 2008 R2. I'm not getting very far with the installation, though. When the installer tries to show me a list of features available, the installer crashes, and I get this error message:

[image: SQL Server setup failure]

I tried enabling assembly binding logging and going through the logs to find more information on the error, but no error seemed to match the last bit of the type name shown in the image.

Comment: Almost looks like you've got the wrong language distro.  (Should post to thedailywtf.com and failblog.org)

Comment: I agree. What language is the OS, and what language is the SQL installer?

Comment: See my answer below, I used a corrupted media set at first, and after figuring that out, forgot to uninstall the (apparently corrupted) setup support files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured it out. I neglected to mention that I tried the setup before with different media, and a md5 check showed that the media was in fact corrupted. As it happens, the installer left bits of the corrupted media on the target server, under the name "Setup Support Components". Removing those via Control Panel fixed the issue.